# ¿Como creo muchos objetos que tengan el mismo contenido?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

```
function nuevoSocio(){
    contador++;
    let wSocio + ${contador} = new Socio(document.getElementById("fname").value, document.getElementById("apellido").value,document.getElementById("dni").value,document.getElementById("email").value,document.getElementById("socio").value)
    alert('estos son su datos ' + wSocio.nombre)
    alert(contador)
}
```

Quiero crear variables que vaya creando variables diferentes.

Hice una variable `contador` que cada vez que entra a una funcion se le suma **+1** mediante `contador++`. Después declaré un nuevo objeto `let_wSocio_=_new_socio(etc,etc,etc)`.

Lo que quiero hacer es agregarle a `wSocio` el contador para que se cree una variable diferente, pero no se como agregarla a `wSocio`. O sea quiero `wsocio + contador`: `wSocio1`, `wSocio2`, `wSocio3`, etc.

¿Alguien tiene idea?

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente se utilizaría [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) para eso, pero se considera [peligroso](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#no_utilice_eval_innecesariamente).

Otra posible solución la tienes en este ejemplo:

```js
var contador = 0
function nuevoSocio(){
    contador++;
    window['wSocio' + contador] = 'hola ' + contador
}

nuevoSocio()
console.log(wSocio1)
nuevoSocio()
console.log(wSocio2)
```

Lo que hacemos aquí es crear una referencia en el objeto [window](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window) (que representa la pestaña de la ventana donde estás ejecutando el código), por lo tanto queda asignada de modo global fuera y dentro del ámbito de la función.

Dicho de otro modo, si necesitas acceder a una variable global, puedes hacerlo con esta sintaxis también:

```js
var variableGlobal = "Soy una variable global"
console.log(window['variableGlobal'])
```